# Simple linguistic analysis without an external API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, nlp

We try to calculate the gender and lemma (the stem) of German words on our website. We need to accomplish this without an external API (i.e. calculate it on the client).

So far we use german-snowball stemmer (which is not too good).

Is there any other solution written in Javascript? All I could find was in Python.

BTW: The website is a huge SPA, so 100 MB dictionary would be no problem.